# Rational number converted to long int

Tags: c, embedded

I have strings representing numeric input data which needs to be converted to integers.
The data is with or without decimal point and needs to scaled to 1e-6 when stored in a long integer.

Example

```
input: "10.123456" to output: 10123456L
input: "1.5" to output: 1500000L
```

The simple approach with floating point arithmetic is

```
float numf;   
sscanf(text,"%f",&numf); 
numf *= 1E6;
result = (long)numf;
```

That is fine but the result is not accurate due to rounding. It also requires floating point maths which I want to avoid.

What's a good method to convert this accurately.
I was thinking about padding the input to the required 6 decimal places and then convert digit by digit into the long int.

Comment: Sounds like you've already figured it out. Find the decimal point, then either pad to six digits or truncate to six digits as necessary.  Then remove the decimal point from the string and convert the resulting integer.

Comment: The method suggested does not in itself cope with negative values or rounding the least significant digit based on the 7th decimal place.  No padding is necessary - you simply need to maintain track of the place value of each digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function `valx6e6()` copes with leading spaces, negative values and rounding by inspection of the 7th decimal place digit (if present).  It uses no floating point code.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SCALE_FACTOR 1000000L

long valx6e6( const char* asc )
{
    long val = 0 ;
    int skip = 0 ;
    while( isspace( asc[skip]) ) 
    {
        skip++ ;
    }

    int signum = asc[skip] == '-' ? -1 : 1 ;

    // Integer part
    val = atoi( &asc[skip] ) * SCALE_FACTOR ;

    // Find decimal part if present
    while( isdigit( asc[skip]) ) 
    {
        skip++ ;
    }

    // Test for decimal part
    const char* decimal = &asc[skip] ;    
    if( *decimal == '.' )
    {
        decimal++ ;
        long place_value = SCALE_FACTOR ;
        while( place_value > 1 && isdigit( *decimal ) )                                               
        {
            place_value /= 10 ;

            // Add fraction
            val += signum * (*decimal - '0') * place_value ;
            decimal++ ;
        }
    }

    // Round according to 7th decimal-place
    if( isdigit( *decimal ) )
    {
        if( *decimal >= '5' )
        {
            val += signum ;
        }
    }

    return val ;
}
```

Tested with the following test cases:

```
val = valx6e6( "1.0" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "1.0" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "1.1" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "1.01" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "1.10" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "-1.0" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "-1.0" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "-1.1" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "-1.01" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "-1.10" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.4" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.04" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.004" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.0004" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.0004" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.5" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.05" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.005" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.0005" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.0005" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.0000005" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "0.0000004" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "1.2345678" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "1.2345674" ) ;
val = valx6e6( "-0.0000005" )
val = valx6e6( "-0.0000004" )
val = valx6e6( "-1.2345678" )
val = valx6e6( "-1.2345674" )
```

Comment: I have corrected this code so that input such as "12abc.345" is interpreted as 12 rather than 12.345.  A possible simple improvement would be to pass the scale factor as an argument rather than a hard-coded constant.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am converting each digit to integer. If decimal part is there then I will go for next 6 digits only.

Lets say string *str* has input. Variable *no* will have output.

```
long int no=0;
count=0;
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
{
     if(str[i]=='.')
     {
          i+=1;
          while((count<6)&&(str[i]!='\0'))
          {
          no=no*10+(str[i]-48);
          count+=1;
          i+=1;
          }
          break;
     }
     no=no*10+(str[i]-48);
 }
 while(count<6)
 {
 no=no*10;
 count+=1;
 }
```

Comment: You need to inspect the 7th decimal place to apply the correct rounding and account for negative values too perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

you can take separate num part and decimal part as below

```
int main(void)
{
    int num, dec;
    char f[16];
    printf("enter floating point number as string\n");
    scanf("%s",f);
    sscanf(f,"%d.%d",&num, &dec); 
    printf("numeric part: %d, decimal part: %d\n", num, dec);
}
```

Sample output

```
enter floating point number as srting
10.123
numeric part: 10, decimal part: 123
```

Comment: If the user enters "1.1","1.10", and "1.01", dec will contain 1, 10, 1 respectively - only the first is correct.

Comment: The sample output has a typo not in the original code. You should test this for real with the example values I have suggested and copy-and-paste the real output.  It still does not work; you cannot store leading zeros in an int, and for the decimal part, leading zeros are significant.

Comment: got it. i misunderstood the issue you pointed. Need to add logic to find if there are any leading zeros in the decimal part

Comment: You need to generate a decimal part that is 100000 for 0.1 and 1 for 0.000001 and add that to `num * 1000000`.  Given that, this is not a good starting point the scanf conversion of the decimal part discards necessary scaling information.